# Unknown property 'zoom'. Declaration dropped

Tags: css, firefox

Firebug is giving me a warning "Unknown property 'zoom'. Declaration dropped." within its console.

What does that mean?

This warning comes from the following CSS declaration:

```
.flexslider .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `zoom` property is not supported in Firefox.
Use the following instead:

```
transform: scale(x);
```